# Blackberry is (almost) here! - Advertising Area 51 sites in definition phase

Tags: discussion, area-51, advertising

I just spotted a Blackberry ad on a SE site that I was not logged in on. I clicked through the link and it went through to a proposal on Area 51 which currently only has 2 example questions and is waiting on 55 followers. The ad itself exclaimed Blackberry is (almost) here! (Sorry no screenshot).

The ad looked quite flashy (custom image, maybe some thought was put into the caption), so although I've never owned a Blackberry I clicked through out of curiosity.

I'm normally logged in most of the time, except when I'm going over some [Hot Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions). So I'm intrigued to find out, do all sites in definition get this sort of exposure?

If so, wouldn't this 'air time' be better placed promoting some of our languishing beta sites *or* is this a matter of scale and due to the large number of visitors we can afford to spend this valuable space promoting newly defined sites?

My understanding was that sites were not promoted until they reached 50% commitment, has this now changed?

Comment: Proposal is here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38297/blackberry-enthusiasts?referrer=H8oz0Y5Gp681u3WXZ3TNrw2

Comment: Almost here? It only has 5 followers... That's (very) far from (almost) here. The (cake) ad is a lie!

Comment: The meta for Area 51 is discussion.area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Actually, it's not, it is http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ for those interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we customarily promote Area 51 proposals once they hit 50 percent, in some instances we will promote a proposal before then. In this case, however, it appears we jumped the gun. Clearly, the Blackberry proposal isn't anywhere near ready to be promoted, and as such, the ad will be taken down, at least until the proposal is better defined. Still, keep an eye out for ads in support of proposals that "aren't quite there yet," and don't hesitate to let us know if you think there is a proposal in Area 51 that you think could benefit from geo- or keyword-targeted advertising on the network. Thanks for keeping an eye out.